# How to redirect to openssl s_server stdin?

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to openssl s_server and s_client connection.

```
server : openssl s_server -cert server.crt -key server.key.pem -dtls

client : openssl s_client -cert client.crt -key client.key.pem -dtls
```

after connection, I can read and write via server console.

But when I give server input by pipe or fifo, it's do not send the message to the client.

`case 1: FIFO`

```
fp = popen("openssl s_server -cert server.crt -key server.key.pem -dtls", "w");
fputs("hello", fp);
```

`case 2: redirection`

```
if server process id is 10000,
echo hello > /proc/10000/fd/0
```

in any case, server do not send "hello" to the client!!
Please help me...

Comment: Same problem, did you manage to find the answer in the end?